# params[:file].path has no method sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

hello im sending a request with a file to my server with a post method
the file arrives but i want to get the path i order to open it but when i get the file with

`params[:file].path`

it says that the hash has no methods
so now i know that this is a hash instead of a file, is there a way to transform this hash to the file i need?

here is how my request looks:

```
{
    "utf8"=>"✓",
    "authenticity_token"=>"vsp2/5YCM9OBFjXASnpnXNmi4oYVlbAEeUhHQzpRd4w=",
    `"file"=>`{
        : filename=>"mass_email.csv",
        : type=>"text/csv",
        : name=>"file",
        : tempfile=>#<File: /tmp/RackMultipart20150422-8224-1vm8siy.csv>,
        : head=>"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"mass_email.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n"
    },
    "commit"=>"Send Mass Email",
    "from"=>{
        "0"=>"\"balblabla\" <email@ik.com>"
    },
    "subject"=>{
        "0"=>"asdasda"
    },
    "template"=>{
        "0"=>"sdasdasdaojoasdijoisjdcxvb"
    }
}
```

also if you know how can i change the way this request arrives with extra \\ everywhere that will very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the filename use

```
filename = params[:file][:filename]
```

To access file use

```
file = params[:file][:tempfile]
```